# Unity crashes when loading projects with Linux and Nvidia GPU

Tags: unity-game-engine, vulkan

I bought a new laptop with an RTX 3050 to be able to work on my unity project on the go. Unfortunately, Unity 2022.3.0f1 always crashes as soon as the editor layout is loaded, even with new projects. I used Kubuntu 23 and 22 and have tested different GPU drivers, but no matter what I try, projects can only be opened with the internal Intel GPU.

Here is the crash report from the Editor.log:

```
[LAYOUT] /home/josef/.config/unity3d/Preferences/Editor-5.x/Layouts/default does not exist. Copying base layouts.
[LAYOUT] About to load /home/josef/.config/unity3d/Preferences/Editor-5.x/Layouts/default/Default.wlt, keepMainWindow=False
VULKAN: GENERAL ERROR: Failed to register present notifier
  Objects:
    #0: { type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_INSTANCE, handle = 0x5622cf2cb030 }


=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================
    0x7f90d911502e - /home/josef/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.0f1/Editor/Data/MonoBleedingEdge/MonoEmbedRuntime/libmonobdwgc-2.0.so : 
    0x7f90d90bdd09 - /home/josef/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.0f1/Editor/Data/MonoBleedingEdge/MonoEmbedRuntime/libmonobdwgc-2.0.so : 
    0x7f90d9043350 - /home/josef/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.0f1/Editor/Data/MonoBleedingEdge/MonoEmbedRuntime/libmonobdwgc-2.0.so : 
    0x5622cb39554c - /home/josef/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.0f1/Editor/Unity : 
    0x7f927983c4b0 - /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 : 
    0x7f9132c653a6 - /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.530.41.03 : 
    0x5622cba29fad - /home/josef/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.0f1/Editor/Unity : 
    0x5622cba2aa13 - /home/josef/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.0f1/Editor/Unity : 
    0x5622cba2b0c3 - /home/josef/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.0f1/Editor/Unity : 
    0x5622cba589c8 - /home/josef/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.0f1/Editor/Unity : 
    0x5622cba588a3 - /home/josef/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.0f1/Editor/Unity : 
    0x5622cba15271 - /home/josef/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.0f1/Editor/Unity : 
    0x5622cba14f53 - /home/josef/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.0f1/Editor/Unity : 
    0x5622cba4de1e - /home/josef/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.0f1/Editor/Unity : 
    0x5622cd28bfef - /home/josef/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.0f1/Editor/Unity : 
    0x5622cd285a3f - /home/josef/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.0f1/Editor/Unity : 
    0x5622cd2859c7 - /home/josef/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.0f1/Editor/Unity : 
    0x5622cd2856f6 - /home/josef/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.0f1/Editor/Unity : 
    0x5622cb6185b7 - /home/josef/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.0f1/Editor/Unity : 
    0x7f927988f18a - /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 : 
    0x7f927991dbd0 - /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 : 

=================================================================
    Telemetry Dumper:
=================================================================
Thread 0x7f90e67ff6c0 may have been prematurely finalized* Assertion at mono-threads.c:702, condition `info' not met, function:mono_thread_info_current, 
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application is shutting down...
[40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Unity.ILPP.Runner.PostProcessingAssemblyLoadContext[0]
      ALC ILPP context 1 is unloading
PlatformDependent/Linux/External/baselib/builds/Include/C/Baselib_ThreadLocalStorage.inl.h(13): Assertion failed (rc == 0)
Caught fatal signal - signo:5 code:128 errno:0 addr:(nil)
PlatformDependent/Linux/External/baselib/builds/Include/C/Baselib_ThreadLocalStorage.inl.h(13): Assertion failed (rc == 0)
Caught fatal signal - signo:5 code:128 errno:0 addr:(nil)
Obtained 6 stack frames.
#0  0x005622cb02bade in TLSAllocator<(AllocatorMode)0>::ThreadInitialize(unsigned long, char const*)
#1  0x005622cbca5b43 in AudioManager::EngineThreadStarted(char const*)
#2  0x005622cbca5954 in AudioManager::systemCallback(FMOD_SYSTEM*, FMOD_SYSTEM_CALLBACKTYPE, void*, void*)
#3  0x005622cdf734d4 in FMOD::Thread::callback(void*)
#4  0x007f927988f18a in pthread_condattr_setpshared
#5  0x007f927991dbd0 in __clone
Obtained 6 stack frames.
#0  0x005622cb02bade in TLSAllocator<(AllocatorMode)0>::ThreadInitialize(unsigned long, char const*)
#1  0x005622cbca5b43 in AudioManager::EngineThreadStarted(char const*)
#2  0x005622cbca5954 in AudioManager::systemCallback(FMOD_SYSTEM*, FMOD_SYSTEM_CALLBACKTYPE, void*, void*)
#3  0x005622cdf734d4 in FMOD::Thread::callback(void*)
#4  0x007f927988f18a in pthread_condattr_setpshared
#5  0x007f927991dbd0 in __clone
Launching bug reporter
Launching bug reporter
cp: cannot stat '/proc/6946/status': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/proc/6946/status': No such file or directory
```

It seems the problem is related to Vulkan, but I couldn't find any posts with a similar error message. I would therefore be very grateful for help.

Comment: Sounds like something you should tell unity

Answer (score 0):

Check your Nvidia driver (Additional driver in Ubuntu). If it is "Manually installed driver" or quite an older version, install the latest driver. That fixed this problem for me and for some other team mates.

Comment: I've tried different drivers. I am currently on version 535, installed via ubuntu-drivers. Which version are you using?

Comment: I've installed the one "Nvidia driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-535 (proprietary)". As a side check - 
what do you get for `vulkaninfo --summary`? 
Is your Unity project HDRP or URP?
If HDRP - have you modified your Linux Graphics API to use only Vulkan as OpenGL is not supported with HDRP.
Also, best bet to use latest Editor, 3.4f1 was release a few days ago. Worth checking with that. 
Depending on your use-case, you might be better off with 2021.3.21f (or whichever was the last LTS on it)